# Getting An Error Message With All My Category Pages

Tags: category

I'm in the process of setting up my new store and all of my category pages produce this error when you try to visit them. Is anyone familiar with this and how to fix the problem? Thanks for the help as always, you guys are excellent.

Here's an example: http://www.lightsy.co.uk/index.php/bottom.html

[image: MY Store]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per as,your log,there are a table  which `doest not exits in magento database.`

This table name is `catalog_category_product` where magento is map the relation `between category and products.`

You need to create this table.this issue has been create may for installation

For this issue run the below mysql query at db as resolution

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_category_product` (
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Category ID',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product ID',
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Position',
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product To Category Linkage Table';

ALTER TABLE `catalog_category_product`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**[Edit]**

---

At your error,your magento system has been `used table prefix  dy5r_` at all tables. but the Ves module does not call  `catalog_category_product`  table with prefix. that is the issue